# unable to spawn process (Argument list too long) after pod install Firebase Analytics pod Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to install the Firebase Analytics pod into my project using Cocoapods. After successfully running pod install and then building my project I get the build error **unable to spawn process (Argument list too long)**.

From my understanding this error has to do with the header search path arguments being too long. When I set my workspace to use the legacy build system the project builds just fine. I however, only want to use the new build system.

It seems to fail when running the shell script "Check Pods Manifest.lock" step of the build process.

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/xxx.build/Debug\ (Staging)-iphonesimulator/OV.build/Script-05BB3CCD2FBD4842F78B0F4F.sh (in target 'xxx' from project 'xxx')
    cd /Users/xxx/Documents/Projects/ov-ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/xxx.build/Debug\\\ \\\(Staging\\\)-iphonesimulator/xxx.build/Script-05BB3CCD2FBD4842F78B0F4F.sh

error: unable to spawn process (Argument list too long) (in target 'xxx' from project 'xxx')
```

It should be noted that I have multiple build configurations for my project like so. Unsure if this could be a cause of the argument list being too long.

```
Debug (Local)
Debug (Staging)
Debug (Production)
Release (Local)
Release (Staging)
Release (Production)
```

Pod File:

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
use_frameworks!

def my_pods
    pod "Apollo", '0.16.0'
    pod 'AlamofireImage', '3.5.2'
    pod 'KeychainAccess', '4.1.0'
    pod 'SwiftUIRefresh', '0.0.1'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.14.0'
end

target 'MY Project' do
  my_pods
end
```

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Open 'File -> Workspace Settings' and set Build System to Legacy Build System. This solved my issue with Firebase CocoaPods installation.

Comment: This is frustrating as in Im surprised why Pods are still falling back on Legacy Build System

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the cocoapods stats using this in your **.podfile** or setting your environment variable directly using **export**

```
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
```

For more info on the stats visit [repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-stats)

Or try following the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226087/error-unable-to-spawn-process-argument-list-too-long-in-xcode-build) OR [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46298811/898057) for more options

Comment: didn't have any luck with this. Is there a special way I'm supposed to set that environment variable? I pasted that line below "use_frameworks!" in my podfile shown in my original question above.

Comment: You can set it at the top of the podfile. This is basically how we set environment variables in a ruby file. Or you can directly try setting the env variable in your terminal or bash with the same key value as above

Answer (score 0):

Delete /Users/issingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData 
Delete 'build' folder of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing you Derived Data folder location near to Disk Root [workspace settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96miN.png)

1. Click in File
2. Access workspace settings
3. In Derived Data change to Custom Location
4. And then set a new short path